# How can a spring attached to a mass cause it to do circular motion in real life?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, spring

I have the following question :

[image: Question]

I am having trouble imagining this that how this configuration will be achieved?
How can a spring with a mass on a plane can do circular motion?
Like if it is elongated, won't the spring just pull it towards center and then only do motion along that line?

Comment: I assume that there is some other unspecified mechanism (like a motor) that would be spinning the mass and spring in a circle; is this what your confusion is about?

Comment: Yes, like how is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physically, and theoretically, this is no different from a satellite in orbit where gravity constantly pulls inwards. No motor would be needed, ideally, just an initial sideways speed. Practically, there might be a lot more factors to take into account with a spring, not least friction forces.

When an object from rest is pulled inwards then it will fall inwards. But if that object is moving sideways initially, then the inwards pull adds an inwards velocity component so the velocity as a whole is angled and not directly inwards. This will trace out an ellipsis.

With higher sideways speeds, it is angled even more and the ellipsis widens. The spring will then not be contracting as much. At some limiting sideways speed, the direction is angled just perfectly so that the ellipsis become a circle and the spring ideally does not contract at all.

This would be comparable to when a satellite is in circular orbit - it is constantly falling towards earth, but it constantly "misses" due to its sideways speed.

Comment: Do I have to extend the spring by force and move it sideways and release?

Comment: @ShekharDangi Yes, it needs the initial stretch so that there is a constant inwards force, as well as an initial sideways speed. Those have to be applied externally.

Answer (score 1):

Particle will want to "escape" the spring by "wanting to go" in a tangential direction, but as far as spring is attached to some pivot point- it will not let particle to do that, and thus will prolong it's length, with this action altogether forcing a particle to rotate about spring pivot point.

A spring elongation can be found from the fact that in this scenario centripetal force will be Hooke's force, so :

$$ k\Delta l = \frac {mv^{2}}{l_0 + \Delta l} \tag 1$$

Now solve eq. (1) for elongation $\Delta l$, and you'll get quadratic equation, like in the form :

$$ \Delta l = a~ \sqrt{b~ + l_0^{~2}} - c~l_0 \tag 2$$

What are an exact constants $a,b,c$,- I'll leave you to figuring out yourself.

Comment: Your reasoning is poor, if Hook's law is centripetal force then why you took radius with elongated length. It means force is streching not compressing.

Comment: Yes, in the long run, spring will be stretching. Try to spin a spring with a mass in one end around your head, and see what happens to a spring length. Spring is stretching due to centrifugal force which in magnitude is same as centripetal Hooke force. Thus, such calculations.

Comment: Besides, exactly at a radius $l_0 + \Delta l$, Hookes force will stop particle radial outwards movement induced by tangential velocity produced centrifugal force.

Answer (score 0):

Seismographs: an earthquake recording instrument.

Mass is lifted by spring, pen is attached to the mass.

When earth shakes side to side, mass resists motion with the aid of spring making the pen draws earthquake wave graph.

In case of plane, the pen or any prepheral device can be attached by the side of the mass.

Answer (score 0):

You just need:

- a spring providing the centripetal force
- an initial condition with tangential velocity $\mathbf{v} =v_{\theta}\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$ and initial position $\mathbf{x}$ s.t. the spring elongation provides the centripetal force with the intensity required for the uniform circular motion with constant tangential velocity $v_{\theta}$,

  $m \dfrac{v_{\theta}^2}{r} = F_c = F_{spring}$,

  being $r = |\mathbf{x}|$, the distance of the mass from the origin at the center of the circle.

If the constitutive law of the spring reads $F_{spring} = k (r-r_0)$, the (initial) distance of the mass from the center of the circular trajectory and the tangential velocity are related by

$m \dfrac{v_{\theta}^2}{r} = k ( r - r_0 )$.

For linear springs with $r_0$, the relation becomes $v_{\theta} = r \sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}$.

Once you match this relation with the initial conditions, if friction is negligible, you get a uniform circular motion.

Answer (score -1):

1. Embed the spring in a tube with rods sticking out on both ends.
2. Place the tube on a low friction table (material, lubricants, etc)
3. Attach a motor below the table, drill a hole, run the axis of the motor through the table and attach one end of the tube/rod.
4. Attach a mass to the other end of the tube/rod. Minimize friction between the mass, spring and everything else
5. Turn on motor

Answer (score -1):

A particle of mass it attached to one end of a spring and moving with constant speed $v$ in circular path, while other end of spring is attached to a fixed end consider as a centre of circular path, letting spring to freely rotate about it.

Now the force exerted by a particle on spring is centrifugal force that causes elongation $l$ in a spring. Where radius of circular path is natural length of spring, as elongation is small so we can neglect increase in radius by elongation. Thus,

$\dfrac{mv^2}{l_0}=kl\Rightarrow l=\dfrac{mv^2}{kl_0}\tag*{}$

Now question of how a particle attached with spring moves in circular path. Attach spring's one end with vertical shaft connected to motor as in a cieling fan. Then motion of a particle is in horizontal plane.

Comment: Your equation is bad. In Hookes law $l$ must be elongation, while in centripetal force denominator (left side) must be radius of centripetal motion **after elongation**, so it must be not $l_0$ (because at this length spring is at start), but $l_0+l$ (when spring experiences particle movement), and then solution becomes more complex, than your given. See my post.

Comment: That's why it was stated that when elongation is small, we can neglect it in radius.

Comment: No, no no. You can't do that, i.e. you can't do "a double standards". If you assume $l=0$, then also in RHS of equation Hooke's force also becomes zero, and hence, no centripetal acceleration of whatsoever. _Same variable_ can't have different values in the same equation, only because of your wry wishes. Variables should be consistent across whole equation.

Comment: Besides, How do you know that elongation will be small ?, namely that $l \ll l_0$ ? If spring stiffness is small, and/or particle tangential speed is very high, then that may be not the case. Even it can be that elongation can be greater than initial spring length,- everything depends on exact spring stiffness and particle velocity. So your assumption may be faulty.

Comment: Hooke's law is good for small changes in length, otherwise it becomes non-linear. In comparision to length of spring, neglect it as adding term.